# SQL - Add ID column for rows if at least one column have the same value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with three columna: col1, col2, col3. I want to create a unique ID if at least ONE of the columns have the same value. For example, if col1 equals A in two instances, regardless of the values of col2 and col3, the id should be the same. Same goes for the other cols, so if col2 equals B, the identifier should be the same regardless of the values of col1 or col2.

This is the expected result.

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | F | G |
| 1 | A | T | Y |
| 2 | B | E | U |
| 2 | T | E | O |
| 3 | H | Y | U |
| 3 | H | B | L |
| 3 | P | B | P |

I've tried using the Dense Rank function but it considers the repeated values in all columns.

Comment: I don't know if this is even possible in SQL because of the overlapping partitions in your ID=3 example.

Comment: Are you trying to create two  same unqie values? are you even listening?

Comment: Hi. Why do BEU and HYU not have the same ID as they have U in common? If your logic is dependant on the row order then how are you defining this order, given that a table has no intrinsic row order?

Comment: Yup - this can be written - but rows need to have an order, and in this question there's no clear `order by`.

Comment: Do the values need to be in the same column in order to get the same ID, because there are a lot of examples in your sample data where there are overlapping values, but in different columns, that have different values.

Comment: Yes, they have to be in the same column. It doesn't matter if they appear in another column. in other words, the same ID is shared if a value for col1 appears in one or more rows OR a value for col2 appears in one or more rows OR a value for col3 appears in one or more rows. If col1 = (1,1) col2 = (1,3), col3 = (a,b) it is the same id because col1 shows a repeated instance more than once. If col1 = (1,2) col2 = (1,3), col3 = (a,b), ids should be different because there are no repeated instances in the same column.

Comment: What would happen if you had 3 rows with values: BEU, TEO, HYO. 1&2 have E in common in col2 so should have the same Id but 2&3 have O in common in col3 so should have the same Id - what Id does the 2nd row get?

Comment: @NickW It looks like your scenario is his ID=3 example above, right?

Comment: What I don't understand is it looks like your ID=2 and ID=3 values should all be the same ID, because BEU and HYU both have a U in the last column.  Wouldn't that make them a match, or do they only match if they are consecutive records?  In my experience, it sounds like you're looking for a transitive closure solution, which I have never found an easy way to handle in SQL.